# error: no such partition Entering rescue mode... grub rescue> ubuntu partition accidentally deleted

Tags: grub2

I am using Windows 8.1
 and Ubuntu 13.10 as in dual boot. I have changed my disk size using disk management. accidentally I delete Ubuntu partition at all. Once I restarted the system, I am getting message 》》 error: no such partition. entering rescue mode. . . Does anybody know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Turn on your computer.

Insert the Windows installation  DVD.

Restart your computer.

Press any key when prompted to do so and follow any instructions that appear.

When the Install Windows page appears, click Repair your computer to access system recovery options.

Follow the instructions.

Source: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/

Comment: I'm not having Windows installation DVD. I will try recover with Ubuntu Installer